# Apply std::begin() on an dynamically allocated array in a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an unique pointer on a dynamically allocated array like this:

```
const int quantity = 6;
unique_ptr<int[]> numbers(new int[quantity]);
```

This should be correct so far (I think, the `[]` in the template parameter is important, right?).
By the way: Is it possible to initialize the elements like in `int some_array[quantity] = {};` here?

Now I was trying to iterate over the array like this:

```
for (auto it = begin(numbers); it != end(numbers); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
```

But I cannot figure out, how the syntax is right. Is there a way?
Alternatively I can use the index like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
```

Is one of these to be preferred?

(Not directly related to the title: As a next step I would like to reduce that to a range-based for loop but I just have VS2010 right now and cannot try that. But would there be something I have to take care of?)

Thank you! Gerrit

Comment: You can't iterate over a `unique_ptr`, it's, well, a pointer. Pointers are not ranges. They have no beginning or end. You just have to use `quantity` somewhere. Also, yes, you can initialize it like this: `new int[quantity]()`.

Comment: Is there some special reason for why you're not just using a vector?

Comment: @GManNickG I just thought there is a way because you can use begin() with an array. Thanks for that initialize-trick. Is this C++11 or was that always possible?

Comment: @Cubic I am working on old code with a lot memory leaks because all the allocated arrays, objects and stuff nearly never get deleted anywhere. So I started to use smart pointers. I should try using vectors for the arrays. Thx

Comment: @Gerrit: That initialization form is from C++03, I believe (definitely pre-C++11). Note that `new T[]` does indeed allocate an array, but the result of that expression is just a pointer to the first element; no size information is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler is supposed to apply this prototype for `std::begin`:

```
template< class T, size_t N > 
T* begin( T (&array)[N] );
```

It means the parameter type is `int(&)[N]`, neither `std::unique_ptr` nor `int *`. If this is possible, how could `std::end` to calculate the last one?

But why not use raw pointer directly or a STL container?

```
const int quantity = 6;
std::unique_ptr<int[]> numbers{new int[quantity]};
// assignment
std::copy_n(numbers.get(), quantity,
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));

const int quantity = 6;
std::vector<int> numbers(quantity, 0);
// assignment
std::copy(cbegin(numbers), cend(numbers),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Now I got it. Thx. The counter part is defined equally `template< class T, size_t N > T* end( T (&array)[N] );` and both know the size because of `N`. Does the compiler deduces the `N` by itself? I don't have to write it explicitly: [link](http://ideone.com/0XlTB4). I will try the other two suggestions. The `vector` was mentioned several times here: Is there a fixed size variant? `array` doesn't work because I know the size only at runtime (not compile time).

Comment: For `int(&)[N]`, it can get the size, but it can't for `std::unique_ptr<int>`, nor `int *`. I just meant these types are not exactly equal. So the compiler cannot deduce N unless you provide an explicit type conversion. And `std::vector` is just fine for fixed size array. If you are not used to using `push_back()` to append elements, just call `vector::resize()` at first, then you can access them via `array[n]`. And, by the way, `vector::data()` can get its raw pointer which type is `T *` and must be compatible with your legacy code.

Comment: `>> std::unique_ptr<int> numbers{new int[quantity]};` Shouldn't this be `std::unique_ptr<int[]> numbers{new int[quantitiy]};` ? Won't the previous one try to use `delete` instead of `delete[]`

Comment: @MattYang: I took some time to study the `vector` type on your advice. You are totally right. That should meet my needs best. @balki: Yes, I think so too. Like I mentioned in my initial question above.

Comment: Yep, you are right, my fault. Forgive my first trying this form :)

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically allocated arrays in C++ (ie: the result of `new []`) do not have sizing information. Therefore, you can't get the size of the array.

You could implement `std::begin` like this:

```
namespace std
{
  template<typename T> T* begin(const std::unique_ptr<T[]> ptr) {return ptr.get();}
}
```

But there's no way to implement `end`.

Have you considered using `std::vector`? With move support, it shouldn't be any more expensive than a `unique_ptr` to an array.