# Is there a safe way to iterate over std::unique_ptr<int[]>?

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code I get a warning with MSVC (C4996) that `std::copy(errors.begin(),errors.end(),pErrors.get());` is not safe. It writes into the raw pointer. Is there an elegant and safe way to iterate over the elements?

The main goal is to prepare a built-in array for a call to a legacy function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

void print_errors_old_function(int argument_count,int* pErrors)
{
    for (int i=0;i<argument_count;++i) { std::cerr << "Error" << pErrors[i] << " "; }
}

void print_errors(std::initializer_list<int> errors)
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> pErrors{new int[errors.size()]};
    std::copy(errors.begin(),errors.end(),pErrors.get()); // warning C4996
    print_errors_old_function(errors.size(),pErrors.get());
}

int main()
{
    print_errors({234,253,334});
    return 0;
}
```

It seems a range based for loop is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15994540/1460794) with `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and that regular for loop would arguably less readable than `std::copy`.

Comment: I'd say you don't need `std::unique_ptr` here, as you don't release ownership, you can just use `std::vector`

Comment: But if I use `std::vector` I still need to convert it for the call to `print_errors_old_function`. How would it help?

Comment: FYI, g++ -Wall thinks this is fine.

Comment: @flatmouse `std::vector::data()`

Comment: @milleniumbug that might be the answer then! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `std::unique_ptr`. `std::vector` will work fine, because `&v[0]` is guaranteed to give you a pointer to the internal buffer, and of course it also has a `size()` member function you can use to interface with C functions. Since C++11, there's also `data()`, which looks nicer than `&v[0]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

void print_errors_old_function(int argument_count,int* pErrors)
{
    for (int i=0;i<argument_count;++i) { std::cerr << "Error" << pErrors[i] << " "; }
}

void print_errors(std::initializer_list<int> errors)
{
    std::vector<int> vErrors(errors);
    print_errors_old_function(vErrors.size(), &vErrors[0] /* or vErrors.data() in C+11 */ );
}

int main()
{
    print_errors({234,253,334});
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how is also gets rid of the warning.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you. (and thanks to milleniumbug)

Comment: `data()` looks nicer and works for empty vector, unlike `&v[0]` which is UB in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but note that were the function like this:

```
void print_errors_old_function(int argument_count,int* pErrors)
{
    for (int i=0;i<argument_count;++i) { std::cerr << "Error" << pErrors[i] << " "; }
    delete[] pErrors; // note this function effectively "consumes" the input
}
```

you wouldn't be able to use this approach, as there is no way to release ownership of the `vector`'s memory. You'd have to make use `std::unique_ptr` the way you do in your question, but you'd have to use `pErrors.release()` instead of `pErrors.get()`.

Visual C++ complains because on several functions which are defined in the standard, but it deems them as "unsafe", which makes standard-conforming code non-compilable. Sometimes, Microsoft provides workarounds, which are only available on Visual C++.

What you can do (choose one of these):

- make use of the suggested Microsoft's workarounds
- disable SDL checks (these checks turn these warnings into errors)
- define `_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in your project. (to disable these warnings)

Comment: This helps me as much as the other answer. The ownership could be accounted for either way (which I didn't consider) and the errors could be made warnings (I was blowing them away with `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`)